# How do I get the date of the Facebook Album as seen on Facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there a way in which I could get the Album Date of an Album as seen on Facebook?

Here is a sample screenshot of one of the albums that I would like the data to be retrieved.

Please check this album https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.470385546361350.110064.186460284753879&type=3

I want to specifically get the **January 24** data.

I have used http://graph.facebook.com/470385546361350 but it only returns the create and update dates as shown below

```
{
   "id": "470385546361350",
   "from": {
      "category": "Local business",
      "name": "Philippine Business for the Environment",
      "id": "186460284753879"
   },
   "name": "BFI, Letran, PBE Ink MOA for GHG Management Course",
   "description": "Start them young. This was the intention of BPI Foundation Inc. (BFI), Colegio de San Juan de Letran, and the Philippine Business for the Environment (PBE) upon forging an agreement last January 22 in training select Letran college students on greenhouse gas (GHG) inventory and management. On hand were Mr. Florendo G. Maranan, Executive Director of BFI; Fr. Tamerlane R. Lana, OP, President of Letran; and Mr. Bonar A. Laureto, Executive Director of PBE.  The program, known as \u201cBPI Greenhouse Gas Inventory and Management Program for University Students,\u201d is made available to 100 Letran college students who have the aptitude in understanding the relationship between environmental stewardship and good business praxis and who are willing to participate in future GHG inventory services. The students are also encouraged to donate one history book to Letran\u2019s partner public school, promoting the spirit of social justice and development.  The syllabus and material for the five-day course, prepared by PBE, will make use of an Activity-Analysis-Abstraction-Application process. This will enable the students to gain technical and applied knowledge and skills on GHG inventory and management that are currently applied in various workplaces.  At the end of the program, the students are expected to become active in GHG inventory and management and other environmental advocacies of Letran.",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=470385546361350&id=186460284753879&aid=110064",
   "cover_photo": "470385596361345",
   "count": 3,
   "type": "normal",
   "created_time": "2013-02-05T08:00:04+0000",
   "updated_time": "2013-02-06T04:36:38+0000",
   "can_upload": false,
   "likes": {
      "data": [
         {
            "id": "100002097532966",
            "name": "Krex Lopezbaliza"
         }
      ],
      "paging": {
         "next": "http://graph.facebook.com/470385546361350/likes?limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=100002097532966"
      }
   }
}
```